# How do you convert binary argv to string?

Tags: c, arduino

I have this C function:

```
void sysexCallback(byte command, byte argc, byte *argv)
{
...
}
```

and I want to convert `argv[0]` (binary) to simple string. I tried things like:

```
char v[10];
strcpy(v,argv[0]);
```

But that gives me an error:

```
Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/string.h:126:14: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

strcpy takes two character pointers as its parameters.  argv[0] is a byte, not a char pointer.  Try

```
strcpy(v,(char *)argv);
```

Alternatively you can make a character pointer and point it to the byte pointer like so:

```
char *string = (char *)argv;
```